# How do I include Ireland in my map in r?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to make a map of the UK and Ireland in R in order to input data points based on latitude and longitudes. I am very new to the program so I'm unsure.

I have written the code:

```
map("worldHires","uk", xlim=c(-12,2), ylim=c(49,59), col="gray90", fill=TRUE)
```

to give me the map of the UK, but everytime I try and incorporate Ireland in it comes up with an error.

Any chance anybody knows how I solve this?

Comment: Did you try exploring ggmap package ?

Comment: [What error](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) did you get? What did you try when you wanted to include ireland?

Comment: Try the rnaturalearth package and `geom_sf()` in the development version of ggplot2, which you can download from its github page.

Answer (score 7):

I am inferring that you are using the `maps` and `mapdata` packages. From the help file shown by `?maps::map`, we can find out that the `regions` argument takes a "character vector that names the polygons to draw". So replacing `"uk"` with `c("uk", "ireland")` does the trick. Note that your chosen `xlim` and `ylim` cut off the Shetlands from the image.

```r
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
maps::map(
  database = "worldHires",
  regions = c("uk", "ireland"),
  xlim = c(-12, 2),
  ylim = c(49, 59),
  col = "gray90",
  fill = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: oh brilliant, that's worked for me. Thank you very much for your help!!